# Using a module in python

Tags: python, module, pip

I'm trying to install and use python for the first time, but I'm having problems using extern librairies.

```
/usr/bin/python /path/core/__init__.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/Users/fabienlamarque/Downloads/RedditAPI/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>   
    import requests  
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Source code :

```
import requests
r = requests.get(r'path/.json')
```

As I surfed around trying to find answers, I found some people telling me to use pip, I indeed used pip and pip3 (with python 2.7.5 and python 3.4.2), the answer is always:

> $ pip install requests
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to
>   upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   Cleaning up...

Which seems like a good thing, I forced the reinstallation of the module several times, but I always have the same problem. My IDE tells me "No module named 'requests'" though.
What did I miss?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running the correct Python executable? Perhaps you have one in `/usr/local/bin/python` but are using `/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: You should look into [`virtualenv`s](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), which make managing which packages are available for a specific project *much* easier.

Comment: Mmmmh upon further inspection, I got python 2.7.5 installed in /usr/local/bin and I have some python files in /usr/bin/ (python, python-config, python2, python-config)

Comment: What version number do you see if you just type `python` (and hit enter) in the shell?

Comment: Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)

Comment: @PM2Ring what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I see /usr/bin/python in there so it's a *nix variant.

you will probably find that `which python` and `which pip` point to different locations.

You can just download the source and use `python setup.py install` assuming that your user has write privilages to the puthon site-packages dir.

Virtualenv for virtualenvironments of even better, conda environments is soemthing I highly suggest learning early on to avoid these headaches on your leaning path.